# Putting numbers inside array at once in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm struggling finding an answer to this: I want to be able to control if a credit card number (let's say '378282246310005') fulfills certain criteria (f.e. does it start with the number 3).

I want to be able to type the whole number at once, and then check certain places in the number (f.e. every second). However, I only managed to put them in an array when typing them one after another, which is annoying:

```
int main()
{

   int user_input[5];
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      printf("Credit Card Number Digit %d\n",i+1);
      scanf("%d",(user_input+i));
   }

   if(user_input[0] == 5)
      printf("MASTERCARD\n");

   else
      printf("INVALID\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see 2 possible ways: 1/ read the whole number as a number (`%d`), then step through the decades (1, 10, 100, 1000 etc) and using the modulo operator; 2/ read the whole number as a string, and step through the individual `char`s inside that string. The latter is probably easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check each digit as it is entered and ignore any non-numeric input, e.g.

```
int main()
{
    int user_input[16];
    int digits = 0;

    while (digits < 16)
    {
        int c = getchar();         // get character
        if (c == EOF) break;       // break on EOF
        if (isdigit(x))            // if character is numeric
        {                          // convert it to int and append to user_input array
            user_input[digits++] = c - '0';
        }                          // (otherwise just ignore it)
    }

    if (digits > 0 && user_input[0] == 5)
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: quotes are mixed up, should be `c - '0';`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helps me out a lot. However, I think it is supposed to be:    "isdigit(c)"

Comment: good answer, but just a note: someone pasting a text (anything, really) by mistake into the window could have pasted something containing enough digits so that you mistakenly assume they entered a credit card number... You may want to further check things (for example only allow N extra chars between each digits? or specifically only discard space & tab & "-" and otherwise exit if something else occurs?)

Comment: @OlivierDulac: sure - I think this is probably just a beginner's learning exercise but in real world code you would validate the check digit etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest scanning a string into an array of `char` and then access this array. The technique is included in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string), where the following code can be found.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char word[20];

    if (scanf("%19s", word) == 1)
        puts(word);
    return 0;
}
```

The snipped reads a string in the array `word`, which can be accessed similar as in your question. Apparently, the maximum length of the string can be given as a parameter in the format string.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I'll read it as soon as I have some spare time.